# POSIX regex in C is not working

Tags: c, regex

I want to match every thing in between two words GET and HTTP. I tried every thing I know. But it is not working. Any help appreciated. The pattern GET.*HTTP should match GET www.google.com HTTP.

Here is the code

Headers:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    regmatch_t pmatch[1];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "GET.*HTTP", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (reti) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Execute regular expression */
    reti = regexec(&regex, argv[1], 1, pmatch, 0);

    if (!reti) {
        puts("Match");
        char *match = strndup(argv[1] + pmatch[0].rm_so, pmatch[0].rm_eo - pmatch[0].rm_so);

        printf("%s\n",match);
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        puts("No match");
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any thing I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: IMHO `GET*.HTTP` should not match "GET www.google.com HTTP". Try to use `GET.*HTTP` instead.

Comment: sory thats right GET.*HTTP. I'll edit it.

Comment: Could you show some code to us?

Comment: OK, so that *should* work. You're doing something else wrong. Please show *what* you're doing (post some code).

Comment: I've just compiled the program and it's working for me. I hope you're passing "GET www.google.com HTTP" in double quotes, otherwise argc=4 and argv[1] is only "GET".

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. Its working. I spent half day on it :(.

Comment: I have a follow up question. How grouping works in POSIX. To match only `wwww.google.com` I used the pattern `GET (.*) HTTP`. But it still matches whole string `GET www.google.com HTTP`. Please give some advice on this.

Comment: That should really be another question, but anyway: the regex matches the entire string; to extract the URL, you need to grab the group in the parentheses, however this regex library does that. Please post the original answer and accept it, so this doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: @Tom I do not have permission to post answer to my own question. Could you please point me to where I can find this (grabing the group in parantheses). I know how to do this in perl but dont know how to do it in C.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the `#include` directives at the top of the source file?  The code you posted won't compile because, among other things, `regex_t` is undeclared.

Comment: ya I tried to do that. But it does not allow me. It said I did not provide enough context explaining the code. When I removed the includes it just accepted it. I'll try once again.

Comment: Sorry, I would have to look it up, I haven't used a C regex library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like my comment was the answer...

The problem is that the command line argument was chopped into 3 strings, making `argv[1]` pointing to `GET` only.

To pass the entire string to the program, you must use double quotes:

```
$ ./regex GET www.google.com HTTP
No match
$ ./regex "GET www.google.com HTTP"
Match
GET www.google.com HTTP
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting it again.